# Is it possible to trigger a contract with a not prunable public trigger message?

Tags: ardor

In the current state pruning is not implemented. Therefore an attached public trigger message should stay in the blockchain until pruning is enabled. When this is the case, will it be possible to make the trigger message unprunable? This could be useful for contract params validation. For example:

If I trigger a contract with the following attached message: `{"contract":"ExampleContract","params":{"veryImportantParameter":"42"}}`

I would like to make this message public (so everybody can validate that I've triggered the contract *ExampleContract* with the parameter *veryImportantParameter* and it's value *42*) and not prunable (so that everybody can validate the message at any time in the future).

Is this going to be possible?

Comment: Which blockchain?

What kind of contract? An ethereum contract? A bitcoin UTXO?

What do you mean by trigger message?

Comment: This question is related to the [Ardor](https://ardorplatform.org) blockchain and its lightweight contract system.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is astroturfing. Many similar questions end up with implausibly detailed and fluffy responses from new users. It is not remotely related to Bitcoin.

Comment: This is a real question and I'm really interested in the answer. If I did something wrong, please tell me. I'll edit the question. All informations are just there to specify the question. I had really no intention to astroturf

Comment: There's multiple tags in this stackexchange site based on alternative cryptocurrencies and blockchain technology at large. Why is it an issue that this question is not related to Bitcoin itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ardor has two levels of pruning. Pruning of messages (like the contract trigger message), data cloud items and shuffling artifacts are already implemented on each child chain. Child chain transaction pruning is scheduled for release later this year.

Only prunable trigger message are supported at the moment to reduce blockchain bloat.

Send your trigger message in plain text and setup an archival node to save it locally even after it is pruned. This will provide you unreputable proof that this message existed at the time when the contract was triggered and other nodes will be load this message automatically from your archival node at a later time.